# Vue Scoped Slots two way data binding between component and slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a scoped slot. I need the content that am passing to the slot to be able to affect the parent template.

This is what i have so far:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :text="text" :msg="msg"/>
    <p>{{text}}</p>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Parent",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
      msg: ""
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <parent>
    <template #default="{ text, msg }">
      <input type="text" v-model="text"/>
      <input type="text" v-model="msg"/>
    </template>
  </parent>
</template>

<script>
import Parent from "./components/Parent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Toolbar
  },
}
```

This does'nt work. How can i do something of the sort?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yes. Though with that title is hard to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. You can't change props (in this case slot props) given to your component(App.vue), but you can do something like this, with a "handler" method.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :text="text" :msg="msg" :setValue="setValue" />
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      msg: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // set the current value with a function
    setValue(e) {
      this[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <parent>
    <template #default="{ text, msg, setValue }">
      Text: {{ text }}<br />
      Msg: {{ msg }}<br /><br />
      <!-- I have named the input fields after the variables in your data object and have the "setValue" method triggered by @input. -->
      <input type="text" name="text" @input="setValue" />
      <input type="text" name="msg" @input="setValue" />
    </template>
  </parent>
</template>

<script>
import Parent from './components/Parent';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Parent
  }
};
</script>
```